# Custom Teams app not showing in mobile client

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have created a custom Teams app using Teams Toolkit for VS Code. I published the app to our company store and it is showing up and working in the Teams desktop and web client.

But somehow it is not showing up in the mobile client on iOS. I even created an App Setup Policy to have the app pinned by default. This is also working in desktop an web client but again nothing shows up in the mobile client.

What could prevent my app from showing up in a mobile Teams client

Comment: Could you please share the manifest json , so that we can try it from our end?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to resolve this by updating the manifest Version from 1.11 to 1.14 and redeploying to the Teams App Store.

Comment: im having the same trouble but this doesnt help :(